# How to fix connection loss in VM?

Tags: linux, virtual-machine, cron

My virtual machine loses the internet connection sometimes on linux and I need to stay connected constantly. So I wrote the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com 
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
    service network-manager restart
fi
```

When I run this script in the console it works but using a `cron` I get:

```
network-manager: unrecognized service
```

What can I do to make this work, or what another approach may help me?

---------------- SOLUTION ----------------

To know why that works launched in console but not during task `cron` I runned in console:

```
echo $PATH
```

Then that displayed:

```
 /usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
```

So I edit my script to:

```
#!/bin/bash
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games

wget -q --tries=10 --timeout=20 --spider http://google.com 
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then 
    service network-manager restart
fi
```

And that works now!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using some sort of Linux Mint similar distro...

It sounds like the "service" program can't find a "network-manager" script to run. It looks in /etc/init or /etc/init.d so you can check there to see what's available.

Or see if auto-complete will tell you (easier IMO). Open a terminal and type:

```
service net
```

then type <kbd>TAB</kbd> several times and should get an auto-completed name like "networkign" and even see some options you can use, like:

```
$ service networking 
force-reload  reload        restart       start         stop
```

So you could try using (may need `sudo` if the script isn't root already):

```
service networking restart
```

Also, you could just `ping` a site like google every minute or so to see if the network is still up, instead of trying to download it.

---

Try checking for a VM bug or strange settings, normally it shouldn't lose it's network connection, unless the host computer loses it...

Comment: Unfortunately TAB doesn't suggest the network-manager service but only networking service which doesn't restart properly the internet connection throw VPN. Indeed network-manager doesn't appear in /etc/init.d/ directory but there are a network-manager.conf file inside /etc/init/. The command `service network-manager restart` work using console but not during a cron task..